# Simple Webscraping in Swift

Tags: swift, scrape

I am just getting started with Swift. I have done a ton of webscrping with B4S in Python, but I am having trouble with Swift.

Does anyone know how I can request html data from a website?

How would I get the html from http://www.example.com/

Or does anyone have a site they would recommend to get started?

Comment: Research `URLSession`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how I can request html data from a website?

As rmaddy notes, `URLSession`.

```
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if  let data = data,
        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    {
        print(string)
    }
}
task.resume()
```